# Am I right in using these adjectives as described below?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I use these adjectives to show the amount of any entity (Sorted from highest to lowest)

### LIQUID/SOLID as applicable:

> I need a lot of milk to drink now-a-days. (Highest in quantity)
>
> I need a good amount of milk to drink now-a-days. (Higher than average in quantity)
>
> Or
>
> I need much amount of milk (oranges) to drink (eat) now-a-days. (Higher than average in quantity)
>
> I need a fair amount of milk to drink now-a-days. (Medium quantity applicable for *liquid*)
>
> Or
>
> I need an average number of oranges to eat now-a-days. (Medium quantity applicable for *solid*)
>
> I need less amount of milk to drink now-a-days. (Lesser than average in quantity)
>
> I need a little amount of milk to drink now-a-days. (Least in quantity for *liquid*)
>
> Or
>
> I need a few oranges to eat now-a-days. (Least in quantity for *solid*)

These usages are entirely made up by none other than myself and I never verified these usages from somebody. I clearly mentioned on what conditions, I use what adjectives. Please suggest me if there are some mistakes in using them; the mistake can be in the very adjective used or the *condition* on which the adjective is used in different cases. Also if I am lacking some more frequently used adjectives, please mention them.

Comment: *Amount of* and *number of* both take *a small*, or *a large* rather than *much* or *less* or *little*. *Much*, *less* and *little* qualify non-count substances (*much milk*), *many* and *few* qualify count substances (*many oranges*)

Comment: As side note, it's _nowadays_, not _now-a-days_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno +1.  I'll add that you may see *now-a-days* in dictionaries (such as the OED), but it should be considered a **historical** spelling.  It's always spelled *nowadays* in today's English.

Comment: @snailboat I guess it would be like reading _to-day_; I would not consider it today's English. `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno, Thank you, I had really no idea about the change! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will reiterate each of your examples in order. In most cases, I am going to give you *only* the corrected version, not the original:

> I need a lot of milk to drink nowadays. (large, not necessarily the largest, quantity; also note the correct spelling of "nowadays")
>
> I need a good (usually: *goodly*) amount.... (higher than average, acceptably yes)
>
> WRONG: I need much amount (incorrect; do not use)
>
> I need a fair amount of milk.... (medium quantity, acceptably yes)
>
> I need an average number of oranges.... (this would not be a common usage, because it specifically refers to a known number, but it can be used casually to suggest *I probably need just about as many as the average person*)
>
> I need less milk (not "less amount of milk;" note that this would NOT mean less than average, but *less than I used to need*)
>
> "A little amount of milk" used in this way is awkward and really not what we say. Various versions of what you mean to say are possible. Here are some examples: "I don't need very much milk." "I need very little milk." "I don't need a lot of milk." These are three possible ways of COLLOQUIALLY saying what you were trying to say with "I need a little amount of milk...."
>
> "I need a few oranges...." can be taken in at least two ways. It might mean "I have to have a few oranges, because I can't live with NO oranges." Or maybe what you are trying to say is, "I really don't need very many oranges." I think you mean the second one, which also could be said this way: "I need ONLY a few oranges...." (You have to have the "only" in there, or else you can't tell which is the correct meaning.)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for clearing all the confusions. I was suspicious of these usages all the time and now you made the usages brightened for me. Thank you and lastly one more request: Are there any more adjectives I left behind which are used by natives in these situations?

Comment: Well, unfortunately, that's a rather large question. There are so many ways to say things in English that I can't really answer. Just one example: I could say "I don't need much milk" by saying "not so much," "not so very much," "not a lot," "really not a lot," "sort of only a little," "maybe just a bit," "not too much," "kind of some but not really all that much," and so on, and so on, and so on....

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make these less awkward by changing the order of what you're saying; that is, put the eat/drink verb in **front** of the oranges and milk:

> I need to drink a lot of milk nowadays.
>   I need to eat a lot of oranges nowadays.
>
> I should be drinking a fair amount of milk nowadays.
>   I need to be eating some oranges nowadays.
>
> I don't need to drink as much milk nowadays.
>   I don't need to be eating so many oranges nowadays.

I think that helps the sentences flow better.